# QML MediaPlayer - How to clear downloaded data

Tags: c++, qt, qml, media-player

I have a problem with MediaPlayer in QML. I use it to watch some online streams. The problem is that MediaPlayer saves all the data it shows so after about 2h of watching 1080p stream, my disk is getting full. After i stop the the stream it removes all downloaded data.

Do you know any way i can tell MediaPlayer to not save it? or remove some of the data while playing?

Media player is nothing special in my code, I just give it the source url and thats it. I looked for some properties that might do something about my problem but with no luck :/

```
MediaPlayer
{
    id: mediaplayer
    source: sourceUrl
    autoPlay: true
    loops: 0
}
```